# PHP CURL inside while loop performance

Tags: php, curl

I have written a CURL handler which is being called inside a WHILE loop. After executing each and every CURL exec, I am freeing up the object resources by setting the CURL handler to NULL. But even though after cleaning up the request also, I am getting a weird error after executing 80K calls like,

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
>   134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 13471 bytes)

And also, I want to know, suppose If a CURL request throws a timeout error, will the error be cached inside the loop?. Why I am asking is, I am trying to execute a API call using the CURL handler. If a API calls fails for the first time, it fails forever even though it gets executed multiple times.

eg: I am tring to call a facebook search API and it returns a error like,

> connect() timed out!

After executing the first time, if I try to run next time or more than anytime, again it returns the same error.

So, can anyone please help me out of this.

**NOTE:**

- I have an idea to use
  CURL_MULTI_EXEC, but before
  implementing I need some suggestions
  from more people like, how to handle
  the above two cases and how to manage
  the CURL object resources.
- How to clean up the cache from
  CURL?

Here is my code,

```
while(true) {
    $curlObj =  triggerCurl($serachUrl);
    return $curlObj;
}


function triggerCurl($url) {
    $url = $url;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Set the default options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure cURL's the reason you're running out of memory? Are you storing data on each iteration?

Comment: 80k hits on the faceook api? sounds like one hell of a nasty scraper.

Comment: @Marc: its not 80k calls for facebook. It includes too many other API calls also and more important thing is, the API calls executed in a time based manner. This is an overall count for three days.